# Meteor Bootstrap 3 Datepicker

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm using rajit datepicker -> https://atmospherejs.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker and I want to know how to rerender a datepicker-range? I tried rerendering the normal datepicker and it works. But with range it doesn't. Only renders correctly on the first render but on rerender it doesn't work anymore.

EDIT:
I used Deps.autorun on rerendering the datepicker.

```
Template.templateName.onRendered (function() {
  var controller = Router.current();
  Deps.autorun(function() {
  var params = controller.getParams();
  $('datepicker-container .input-daterange').datepicker('remove');
  $('datepicker-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
      format: "dd M yyyy",
      todayHighlight: true
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dp.getUTCDate')
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @Kyll Ok i'll put a code snippet on my question

Comment: Use `Tracker.autorun()`